# Flutter remove widget shortcut in VS Code

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to create a keyboard shortcut (Control+X, for example) in VS Code to perform the same action as *Refactor* (Control+Shift+R) and *Remove this widget* while focusing the text cursor on the Widget name (Scaffold, Container...)?

If that is possible, would then be possible to *cut* a widget structure (name and properties) and then *copy* that widget structure to wrap another widget like the *Wrap widget with*.. refactor option?

[image]

Comment: with `Developer: Set Log Level` you can se which commands are called, and then you can create a sequence and use extension `multi-command` to execute the sequence